# Kendo DataSource with sending dynamic data to the server

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm new to Kendo and from several days I'm trying to figure out how to populate kendo grid with search data. My case is the following:

I have javascript viewmodel:

```
sl.kendo = function () {
    var billingReportViewModel = kendo.observable({
        billingReportCriteria: [],
        executeSearch: function (e) {
            var $grid = $("#gridResults").data("kendoGrid");
            $grid.dataSource.read();
            $grid.refresh();
        }
    });
    return {
        billingReportViewModel: billingReportViewModel
    }
} ();
```

And I initialize the billingReportCriteria from the server with this function:

```
var initCriteriaViewModel = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetBillingReportCriteria',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (model) {                
            **$.extend(sl.kendo.billingReportViewModel.get("billingReportCriteria"), kendo.observable(model));**
            // bind to the viewModel
            kendo.bind($("#searchTable"), sl.kendo.billingReportViewModel);
        }
    });
}()
```

Than I declare my grid DataSource that sends this billingReportCriteria to the server as parameter:

```
var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "GetBillingReportResults",
            data: JSON.stringify(sl.kendo.billingReportViewModel.get("billingReportCriteria")),               
            cache: false,
            type: "POST"
        }
    },       
    schema: {
        data: "Items",
        total: 10 // total number of data items is returned in the "count" field of the response
    }
});
```

And I init my kendo grid:

```
$("#gridResults").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
          {
              field: "Name"
          },
          {
              field: "Title"
          }],
    dataSource: gridDataSource,
    autoBind: false
});
```

When I execute the search from the view model 'executeSearch' I go the server, but the billingReportCriteria is empty! When I check the 'billingReportViewModel' value from F12 Chrome tools everything seems to be OK, but when I check the value of 'sl.kendo.billingReportViewModel.billingReportCriteria' or 'sl.kendo.billingReportViewModel.get("billingReportCriteria")' - it's empty though 'sl.kendo.billingReportViewModel.get("billingReportCriteria.Name")' for example has the right value!
Can you suggest what the problem is? Somehow I can't send the right 'billingReportCriteria' to the server!

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the following thing. When I get the method on the server that is responsible for returning the results the only way I can get the passed parameters is by using the Response.Form or Response.QueryString in the body of the method. How can I pass the arguments to that method so I can get them like this:

```
public JsonResult GetBillingReportResults(string billingCriteria)
{
    string criteria = Request.Form["billingCriteria"]; //I can do it like this, but I want to pass the arguments as method parameters
}
```